# Can the Macbook 12 inch handle XCode/Eclipse for Android/iOS development?

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, xcode

I know that Macbook 12 inch was created for battery life and it's lightness instead of performance, but I am really curious about it's performance for development purposes.

Did anyone actually test it on the real device? If so, what do you think? If not, what's your opinion anyways?

While XCode is compiling, will I be able to open safari without seeing "the rainbow"? Slow compilation is not a problem, but I want to know if it hogs the whole OS or not.

Comment: I used to have a MacBook Air 2010 and that worked fine for development (I make simple apps). Seeing the bench mark tests for the 12" MacBook it seems to fit in with the 2011 MacBook Air so it should be fine. When I went to the Apple Store on the 10th I said to them that I needed the computer for note taking and programming and he said it should be fine (I do C++). I cannot say for my self since they did not have any in store so I got a MacBook Pro instead.

Answer (score 5):

The question is quite opinion based. Can it handle development - absolutely. Will it be fast enough - now that's a matter of your personal reception of "fast enough".

The MacBook is quite a capable machine. It will run Development-Tools without any issues. It will perform lower than a MacBook Pro CPU and GPU-wise, so it really depends on your personal needs. Use something like Activity Monitor to keep an eye on your current system load during your daily tasks. If your machine is often at it's limits, you will have to take sacrifices with a MacBook. If your machine idles a lot and is only pushed to the edge rarely, you'll probably be happy with the machine.

Comment: Thanks. While XCode is compiling, will I be able to open safari without seeing "the rainbow"? Slow compilation is not a problem, but I want to know if it hogs the whole OS or not.

Comment: I got the 2016 CoreM5 and When I had open 2 Browsers with each 10 tabs who had more than just plain HTML in them you will hog the system and will need to wait until it unhogs. With an IDE that indexes your code + Multiple Tabs you will not be happy with the 12 inch. Other than that really fine machine, cant wait for the new Pros to come out.